# Hello all, I am getting SAP DBTech JDBC: [2]: general error: Remote export failed: while exporting a table into csv file

Tags: hana

I am getting below error wgile exporting a table into csv in hana studio.
SAP DBTech JDBC: [2]: general error: Remote export failed: export size exceeds 20% of available memory, please use server-local export.
My table has 186 millions records
Please let me know how to resolve this issue and how to run in server - local export

Answer (score 0):

Pallavi there is export limitation applied to the HANA users. You can check those by going into settings of your hana studio. Thats one you need to sort out but if there those many rows as you mentioned above i would suggest to slice the extract into multiple extracts.

Here is the admin settings link from SAP which will guide you to the particular setting i am referring to:

https://help.sap.com/viewer/6b94445c94ae495c83a19646e7c3fd56/2.0.03/en-US/c06b0a63bb5710148bb5e18dfd71c237.html

Look for query limit and exported data to file